# How to properly close the connection created in an initializerr?

Tags: python, sqlite

My question is about how to close the 'conn' object after the queries. The query can be many.

```
class MusicAPI(object):

    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("Loading music database ...")
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('data/music.db')

    def search_by_artist(self, artist, song=None, genre=None):
        assert (artist is not None), "artist must be provided in search_by_artist!"

        query = "SELECT * from musicians where artist == '" + artist + "'"
        if song is not None:
            query += " and song == '" + song + "'"
        if genre is not None:
            query += " and genre == '" + genre + "'"

        results = set()
        cursor = self.conn.execute(query)
        for row in cursor:
            results.add(row[0])

        return results
```

Then I can use the API to do query:

```
class SearchMusic(object):
   def name(self):
      return "search_music"

   def query(self, query_term):
       music_api = MusicAPI()
       r = music_api.search_by_artist(query_term)
```

How to properly close the "conn", which is created in the **init** function?

Comment: `query += " and song == '" + song + "'"` => SQL Injection

Comment: `self.conn.close()`? Is this part of some app with multiple threads/processes?

Comment: Single thread. The question is where to put the 'self.conn.close()'? Is not good to put it in "search_by_artist". Right? since it has to be called for each query